# JSF Richfaces Autocomplete breaks page styling

Tags: css, jsf, autocomplete

I have just used the rich-faces autocomplete. It works well, but it breaks the styling of my page.

The autocomplete component is

```
<rich:autocomplete id="hsCode" styleClass="form-control" mode="client" required="true" minChars="2" value="#{productProfileListController.hsCode}" autocompleteMethod="#{productProfileListController.autocomplete}" />
```

Below is the actual page styling.

[image: The actual page styling]

And next, when the autocomplete shows up, **the styling breaks**, as seen in the screenshot below. The text box where 123 is written is the autocomplete text box.

[image]

Can anyone please help?  Thanks in advance.

The solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21330043/richautocomplete-breaks-style-of-the-page) does not work.